# Haskell function to parse a string and return any urls found

Tags: parsing, haskell

What I've been looking for is the function in the title. I could write something in parsec, but before I do, anyone know of anything like this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find this useful: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html#queries-listing-urls

Answer (score 3):

I think [regexes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base) are a better tool for the job.  Parsec is good when the whole document has a rigid syntax -- regexes are good for finding well-formed data within random trash.

[Here's one](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm) (I haven't checked it).

Answer (score 0):

There is an out-of-the-box Megaparsec solution for this now. Combine
[`Text.URI.parser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/modern-uri/docs/Text-URI.html#v:parser)
with
[`Replace.Megaparsec.sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap).